# Heroku logs ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_collector'

Tags: python, flask, heroku

My app.py flask app will run locally but when I deploy it using heroku I am getting this error. My data_collector.py file is in the same directory as my app.py file so I am not sure why this is happening when I try to deploy my application.

My imports in app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

from data_collector import collect_data

import sqlite3
```

I updated my requirements.txt file so that is not the issue. I am stumped.

Logs:

```
2024-02-16T20:04:03.651435+00:00 app[web.1]: from data_collector import collect_data
2024-02-16T20:04:03.651435+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_collector'
2024-02-16T20:04:03.651577+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-02-16 20:04:03 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2024-02-16T20:04:03.690394+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-02-16 20:04:03 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Worker (pid:8) exited with code 3
2024-02-16T20:04:03.693505+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-02-16 20:04:03 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Worker (pid:7) was sent SIGTERM!
2024-02-16T20:04:03.791000+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-02-16 20:04:03 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
2024-02-16T20:04:03.791047+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-02-16 20:04:03 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2024-02-16T20:04:03.867661+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2024-02-16T20:04:03.889332+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add "__ init __.py" inside the folder of "app.py".Check: [What is **init**.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) This will help you import other .py files in the same path of the "app.py"

If you use docker as a container for your application, you might need to copy the file paths(that you want to import) along with your main file "app.py".